# How to order css property?

Tags: html, css

When I placed margin properties on top of others it didn't work? Then when I placed margin at bottom it worked as I desired. Why?
Can anyone tell me the sequence of writing properties?

```
header {
    margin-top:10px;    
    width:80%;
    height:46px;
    margin: auto;    
    background-color:#fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px green;          
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with `didn't work`? If you place `margin: auto;` above `margin-top:10px;` then then top margin is `10px` and the others are `auto` if you place it below `margin-top` is overwritten, with `auto`

Answer (score 0):

In css the last value you set to a property is what matters... In the code you posted, the margin-top: 10px will be overriden by margin: auto (the top margin will be set to auto)

If you move the margin:auto as the first element, then your top margin will have 10 pixels. You can also force a value using marging-top: 10px !important, but that is hard to mantain if you use it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS parser reads the document from top-to-bottom, allowing you to override properties later. This is essential to the *Cascading* Style Sheet, as explained [in the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html).

`margin` sets all four margins. You need to set the most specific thing at the bottom of your CSS document, ie:

```
margin: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
```

Equally, you can specify the margins on one line (clockwise from the top):

```
margin: 10px auto auto auto;
```